# Define an operator that's not already built into the syntax

Tags: python, syntax

I'd like to know if there is a way to define a operation that isn't built into Python - rather than creating some member function of an object and calling it.

For example, define an "absolute value" operation for a class `C`, then invoke it as `|C|`.

If not, I know it's possible to import operations (I think abs val is in math), so could I look up the tags for operations I import? By "tag" I mean what would replace `eq` in  `def __eq__(self):`

or is there no "tag" for imported operations?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean. Are you trying to attach a function to a class/object? Can you explain your intent more?

Comment: define "operation". Do you expect a member to be accessed/called, or a syntactic construct?

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP wants to make a syntax construct like being able to use `|x|` for absolute values, which is as far as I know, not possible with python

Comment: [Data model](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types)

Comment: Clarified the phrasing in the 1st part (this made the ending redundant). Unsure what are the "imported operations" that replace strings in code. Is it like Perl's source filters?

Answer (score 2):

Python's syntax is defined by the interpreter's implementation. You cannot add your own syntax without modifying it.

Unless you somehow manage to "preprocess" the source into the "normal" form before it reaches the interpreter.

You may have some luck with PyPy where the interpreter is implemented in Python itself. You need to make a separate unit of "normal" code that would

- somehow access PyPy's objects (e.g. by importing corresponding modules)
- modify them
- feed the "unusual" source to the modified interpreter

Do note that your proposed construct will need to be parsed and thus be distinguishable from other language constructs. Your `|x|` is, at first sight, indistinguishable from the `|` operator (bitwize OR).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you want to add something to the already existing "mappings" , such as

```
+ --> __add__
& --> __and__
```

etc.?

Then I have to disappoint you - you cannot define such a thing as

```
|...| --> __abs__.
```